# How to add multiselect for has_many through relationship in activeadmin form

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord, activeadmin

I have two models Degree and College connected many_to_many connection via Discipline table.

```
class Degree < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :disciplines
  has_many :colleges, :through => :disciplines
end 

class Discipline < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :college
  belongs_to :degree
end


class College < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :disciplines
  has_many :degrees, :through => :disciplines
end
```

I want to display multiple select (or checkboxes) with a degrees on the college new/update forms.  How to do that?

Answer (score 0):

In the College ActiveAdmin resource you can use the `has_many` method in the form block:

```
ActiveAdmin.register College do
    #...

    form do
      #...
      f.has_many :disciplines do |df|
        df.input :degree
      end
      #...
    end
    #...
end
```

This will be a multiselect select input by default.
Find out more: https://github.com/activeadmin/activeadmin/blob/master/docs/5-forms.md#nested-resources

Comment: While this answer is probably correct and useful, it is preferred if you include some explanation along with it to explain how it helps to solve the problem. This becomes especially useful in the future, if there is a change (possibly unrelated) that causes it to stop working and users need to understand how it once worked.